# Making an absolute element appear below a fixed element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am having issues with my website where my fixed header is appearing above an absolute paragraph [here](https://home.josephmurphy4.repl.co/html/about-me.html).

Is there any way I could fix this?

Comment: Can you please share your relevant "*[mcve]*" code here, in your question? My suggestion would be to avoid using absolute positioning, and instead take advantage of grid or flex box layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your CSS add `z-index: 10;` to your `#headerback` div.

```
#headerback{
    background-color: #430A6C;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

`z-index` manages the stacking context of elements. If you want something to appear in a higher context (meaning above other elements) then give the `z-index` a higher number. 0 is default.

Answer (score 1):

@matt-croak's solution will work in your case. Here's some good to know CSS fundamentals of positioning - when you use `position: absolute` for an element, the positioning attributes like `top` `left` `right` and `bottom` rely on the nearest parent element that has it's position set to `relative`.

Make sure you create a wrapping div for all of your elements other than the topbar and set `position: relative` on the wrapper.

Subsequently, all the elements within the wrapper div will use it as a reference for positioning.